# Where can I find binance python documentation for USD-M futures?

Tags: python, bots, documentation, trading, binance

I am trying to build a cryptocurrency trading bot using binance as my chosen exchange. I have found the binance python documentation but this seems to be geared to spot accounts. I want to design my trading bot to trade on my USD-M futures account.

Where can I find documentation to help with this?

Comment: I would contact the Binance team for help with their documentation. This question is too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for that Oliver, I'll try that

Comment: Binance has a complete chaos in their documentation, mixing all APIs in different URLs, IPs etc. it's a nightmare!